# sorting hash by one of the key values

Tags: ruby

I have `@hash` that looks like this:

```
[1, {:clid=>1, :nvz=>4, :tip=>"IP", :name=>"Mark", :record=>"some text"}] 
[2, {:clid=>2, :nvz=>-5, :tip=>"AO", :name=>"Tom", :record=>"another text"}] 
[3, {:clid=>3, :nvz=>0, :tip=>"AO", :name=>"Pit", :record=>"another text"}]
```

How can I sort this hash so that iterations will be ordered by `:nvz` and look like this:

```
[2, {:clid=>2, :nvz=>-5, :tip=>"AO", :name=>"Tom", :record=>"another text"}] 
[3, {:clid=>3, :nvz=>0, :tip=>"AO", :name=>"Pit", :record=>"another text"}] 
[1, {:clid=>1, :nvz=>4, :tip=>"IP", :name=>"Mark", :record=>"some text"}]
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be an array of arrays? Why are there no commas at the end of these lines?

Comment: I've just showed each itteration. @hash looks like this {1=>{:clid=>1, :tip=>"IP", :name=>"Mark", :record=>"some text", :nvz=>0}, 2=>{:clid=>2, :tip=>"OO", :name=>"Tom", :record=>"another text", :nvz=>-10}, 3=>{:clid=>3, :tip=>"IP", :name=>"b", :record=>"and text", :nvz=>4}, 4=>{:nvz=>"n", :tip=>"ТОО", :name=>"c", :record=>"no record"}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand original hash looks like this?

```
{
  1 => {:clid=>1, :nvz=>4, :tip=>"IP", :name=>"Mark", :record=>"some text"},
  2 => {:clid=>2, :nvz=>-5, :tip=>"AO", :name=>"Tom", :record=>"another text"},
  3 => {:clid=>3, :nvz=>0, :tip=>"AO", :name=>"Pit", :record=>"another text"}
}
```

If true try this

```
@hash.sort_by{ |k,v| v[:nvz] }
```

**PS**

As far as your original hash has got NON INTEGER nvz ('n') so you should convert it to integer:

```
@hash.sort_by{ |k,v| v[:nvz].to_i }
```

**PPS**

If you need to sort `n` as `999`:

```
@hash.sort_by{ |k,v| v[:nvz] == 'n' ? 999 : v[:nvz] }
```

Comment: sorry, rails says: comparison of Fixnum with String failed

Comment: {1=>{:clid=>1, :tip=>"IP", :name=>"Mark", :record=>"some text", :nvz=>0}, 2=>{:clid=>2, :tip=>"OO", :name=>"Tom", :record=>"another text", :nvz=>-10}, 3=>{:clid=>3, :tip=>"IP", :name=>"b", :record=>"and text", :nvz=>4}, 4=>{:nvz=>"n", :tip=>"ТОО", :name=>"c", :record=>"no record"}}

Comment: So in your last row `nvz` is equal to `n`, so how should you sort numbers and strings? look my update

Comment: sorry, I've got an order of : 0, -10, 4, n.  I need: -10, 0, 4, n. I can substitute n with 999